# Copy-PnPFile returns 401

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am traying to copy files betwen SP Document Librarys, with PnP PowerShell command "Copy-PnPFile",

but I get "**Copy-PnPFile : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized**"

In the script before this comand I am reading, items, creating folder and it works, only Copy-PnPFile dont work.

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $Item["FileRef"] -TargetUrl $TargetFileUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure **$Item["FileRef"]** is a `relative path`. Of course **$TargetFileUrl** should also be a `relative path`.

---

[Microsoft Official:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/copy-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)

Copy-PnPFile:Copies a file or folder to a different location. This location can be within the same document library, same site, same site collection or even to another site collection on the same tenant. Currently there is a 200MB file size limit for the file or folder to be copied. Notice that if copying between sites or to a subsite you cannot specify a target filename, only a folder name.

---

**Here is a nice article for your reference：**

- [SharePoint Online: Copy File Between Document Libraries using
  PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-copy-file-between-document-libraries-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Hi, source path : "/sites/OriginalDocumentList/OSR Safety - K_Info 4.docx"                                    target path: "/sites/TranslationAppDocuments/OSR Safety - K_Info 4.docx"   and it doesn't work. Thank you, Matjaz

Answer (score 1):

My mistake.
In source and target relative path forgot to include "SiteCollectionURL".

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? If your issue is resolved, please remember to accept the helpful answer.